# Way to get dates for weekly, fortnightly, and monthly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

A user adds an income or expense. If he classifies it as a recurring transaction, he picks from a frequency_dropdown containing (weekly, fortnightly, monthly). The user also inputs the start date. I would like to get the dates for the frequency selected starting from the date the user provides.

For example, the user inputs 06-13-2016 and weekly (current date: 06-28-2016), I would like to get the dates 06-20-2016 and 06-27-2016.

HTML Dropdown

```
<select name="frequency_id">
    <option value="1">weekly</option>
    <option value="2">fortnightly</option>
    <option value="3">monthly</option>
</select>
```

Controller

```
public function getDates($frequency, $start_date) {
    //$start_date is string e.g 06-23-2016
    //$frequency is also string e.g weekly, fortnightly, monthly
    ...
    ...
    return $dates; //array returned
}
```

It's ok if i convert the string date to DateTime object, as long as I get the dates.

I would like to get the dates returned in an array of dates or similar.

I have no idea how to proceed with it. Please help.

Comment: What is the data type of start_date? DateTime object? String? In which variable do you have the recurrence? Is it a string? Could you provide a bit more code (including the HTML dropdown, ...etc)? Do you expect the result to be a string, array of string, DateTime objects...?

Comment: @trincot done edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) for this task. It's already included with Laravel. :)

Let's code a helper outside the controller to do this task:

*app/Helpers/DateHelper.php* (just create that file)

```
<?php
namespace App\Helpers;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class DateHelper
{
    public static function next_dates($start_date, $frequency)
    {
        $dates = [];

        $start_date = Carbon::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $start_date);
        $end_date = Carbon::today();

        while ($start_date->lte($end_date)) {
            switch ($frequency) {
                case 'weekly':
                    $start_date = $start_date->addWeek();
                    break;
                case 'fortnightly':
                    $start_date = $start_date->addWeeks(2);
                    break;
                case 'monthly':
                    $start_date = $start_date->addMonth();
                    break;
            }

            if ($start_date->lte($end_date)) {
                $dates[] = $start_date->format('m-d-Y');
            }
        }

        return $dates;
    }
}
```

In your controller, just use the helper:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use App\Helpers\DateHelper;

class YourController extends Controller
{
     public function index(Request $request)
     {
         $dates = DateHelper::next_dates(
             $request->input('start_date'),
             $request->input('frequency')
         );

         return view('your-view')->with(compact('dates'));
     }
}
```

Comment: when adding a month, how does it behave? example 6-23-2016, if a month is added, i want to get 7-23-2016. same day.

Comment: or how about 5-31-2016. june only ends at 30

Comment: What do you want? For the weekly frequency you said it should stop until the current date. The requirements are not clear on how many dates you expect for each frequency. Will you have an end date?

Comment: sorry. i think I'm gonna use your answer. I'm just curious about how addMonth() would behave. If for example, the user inputs 1-31-2016. I'm confused how addMonth would do it? February only ends at 2-29-2016

Comment: If $start_date was 01-31-2016, considering it would stop until today (per the requirement stated), it would return 02-03-2016, 02-04-2016, 02-05-2016 and 02-06-2016. This is the way PHP adds a month to a given date. Since the requirements doesn't addressed the expected behavior, I assumed that the default date manipulation behavior would be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
function getDates($frequency, $start_date, $end_date = null) {
    //$start_date is string e.g 06-23-2016
    //$frequency is also string e.g weekly, fortnightly, monthly
    //$end_date is optional string: limit to the dates to be generated. Default = today

    // Convert to use slashes, so PHP will interpret in m/d/Y format,
    // otherwise it would expect d-m-Y.
    $dt = new DateTime(str_replace("-", "/", $start_date));
    $dtUntil = new DateTime(str_replace("-", "/", $end_date ? $end_date : date("m-d-Y")));
    // conversion table: frequency to date modifier string
    $modifiers = [
        "weekly" => "+1 week",
        "fortnightly" => "+2 weeks",
        "monthly" => "+1 month"
    ];
    $modifier = $modifiers[$frequency];
    $dt->modify($modifier);
    while($dt <= $dtUntil) {
        $dates[] = $dt->format("m-d-Y");
        $dt->modify($modifier);
    }
    return $dates; //array returned
}
```

Example call:

```
$dates = getDates("weekly", "06-13-2016", date("m-d-Y"));
```

You'll need to provide something to end the array, so I have provided the end date until which to produce dates, as third parameter to the function. If you don't provide it, it will default to today, so in the above example it could have been omitted.

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/596753).

Comment: instead of using count, can it stop only until the current date (today)? for example, today is 6-28-2016. so it'll only return 6-20-2016 and 6-27-2013. It won't include 7-05-2016 since it is beyond the current date.

Comment: Sure, I updated my answer. Now third argument is end-date. Pass today as argument to get what you just said.